# Codewars R Challenge: for i from 1 to n, do i % m and return the sum | Looking to optimize the code

Tags: r, performance

This is a rather simple question but somehow my code either takes long time or consumes more resource. It is a question asked in www.codewars.com which I use for R Programming practice.

Below are the two versions of the problem I coded:

## Version 1 :

```
f <- function(n, m){
# Your code here
if(n<=0) return(0) else return((n%%m)+f((n-1),m))
}
```

## Version 2:

```
#Function created to calculate the sum of the first half of the vector 
created

calculate_sum <- function(x,y){
sum = 0
for(i in x){
  sum = sum + i%%y
}
return(sum)      
}

#Main function to be called with a test call

f <- function(n, m){
# Your code here
#Trying to create two vectors from the number to calculate the sum 
#separately for each half

if(n%%2==0){

first_half = 1:(n/2)
second_half = ((n/2)+1):n

} else {

first_half = 1:floor(n/2)
second_half = (ceiling(n/2)):n
}

sum_first_half = calculate_sum(first_half,m)
sum_second_half = 0

for(j in second_half){
sum_second_half = sum_second_half+(j%%m)
}

return(sum_first_half+sum_second_half)

}
```

I am trying to figure out a way to optimize the code. For the first version it gives the following error message:

> Error: C stack usage  7971184 is too close to the limit
>      Execution halted

For the second version it says my code took more than 7000 ms and hence was killed.

Can someone give me a few pointers on how to optimize the code in R??

Comment: loops are dead slow in R: you need to start thinking with vectors (i.e. how can I compute *all* the answers at once?) Something like `function(m,n) sum((1:n) %% m)` will be much, much quicker (and is also easier to understand)

Comment: Thanks @JDL but this too was killed. Error message saying "Process was terminated because it took more than 12000 ms".

Comment: @VikashKumar how big is n here?

Comment: Are you required to actually calculate all of `i%%m`? Because there are alternative formulae for this expression that will be a lot quicker to calculate...

Comment: @SmileyBcc We cannot see the test cases but i believe it somewhere around 10 raised to the power 12 or more. That was one of the caveats mentioned in the problem staement.

Comment: Here is a sample test case : f(n=10, m=5) // returns 20 (1+2+3+4+0 + 1+2+3+4+0)

Answer (score 2):

The optimisation is mathematical, not programmatical (though as others have mentioned, loops are *slow* in R.)

Firstly, note that `sum(0:(m-1)) = m*(m-1)/2`.

You are being asked to calculate this `n%/%m` times, and add a remainder of `(n - n%/%m)(n - n%/%m + 1)/2`. So you might try

```
f <- function(n,m){
  k <- n%/%m
  r <- n - k*m
  return(k*m*(m-1)/2 + r*(r+1)/2)
}
```

which is a much less complex calculation, and will not take very long regardless of how large n or m is.

There is a risk that, if `n` is greater than 2^53 and `m` does not have enough powers of 2 in its factorisation, there will not be enough precision to calculate `k` and `r` accurately enough.

Comment: m mod m = 0, not m, so you should calculate `sum(1:(m-1))`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just Realized it is actually a trick question
I would do

```
 n%/%m *sum(1:(m-1)) + sum( 0:(n%%m))
```

Loop are real slow in R. Also, from my experience recursive function in R doesnt help much with the speed and it takes lots of memory

Comment: If `m` is large, then `sum(1:(m-1))` will still take a long time. Better to replace with its analytical equivalent (and more numerically stable, too)

Comment: Thanks @JDL. Indeed sum(1:(m-1)) seems to take a longer time. JDL's solution worked well taking less amount of time. Definitely a learning for me here.